# jdbi3 withHandle throwing error in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jdbi

withHandle is giving error saying 'not enough information to infer type variable X'.

but if I use

```
val count = jdbi.withHandleUnchecked { handle ->
                    handle.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM levelmaster WHERE `LevelName` = 'Silver' AND `LevelId` >= :ugradingLevel")
                            .bind("ugradingLevel", ugradingLevel)
                            .mapTo(Int::class.java)
                            .findOnly()
                }
```

withHandleUnchecked it's not throwing any error.

Here's my code : (using withHandle)

```
handle = jdbi.open() 
val names = jdbi.withHandle { handle ->
                    handle.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM levelmaster WHERE `LevelName` = 'Silver' AND `LevelId` >= :ugradingLevel")
                            .bind("ugradingLevel", ugradingLevel)
                            .mapTo(Int::class.java)
                            .findOnly()
                }
```

Comment: I have used jdbi.installPlugin(SqlObjectPlugin())
                        .installPlugin(KotlinPlugin())
                        .installPlugin(KotlinSqlObjectPlugin()) also...still error

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue earlier today. It took me a bit to figure it out.

Based on the error message, the compiler can't infer what type X is. X is a type parameter for the useHandle method, which is meant to specify what type of exception (if any) our HandleConsumer will return. In Kotlin, we represent the HandleConsumer with an anonymous function, so really this type parameter should be whatever exception our lambda might throw. If you take a look at the definition of the useHandle method, it becomes a lot easier to understand what you need to do :).

So, the way to fix this error is to specify an explicit type after useHandle.

This should fix the error:

```
jdbi.useHandle<Exception> { handle ->
    handle.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM levelmaster WHERE `LevelName` = 'Silver' AND `LevelId` >= :ugradingLevel")
                            .bind("ugradingLevel", ugradingLevel)
                            .mapTo(Int::class.java)                            
                            .findOnly() 
}
```

The key difference here is `jdbi.useHandle<Exception>{ ...`

rather than just `jdbi.useHandle{ ...`

I hope that helps! It definitely tripped me up for a minute too.